# Python 3 - Does the direct manipulation of a class' attribute override the same attribute for its objects making the attribue purely static?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-variables, python-class

While learning about how classes work in Python I came across a class definition example which behaved kind of strangely in my eyes.

The purpose of the example was to demonstrate how the behaviour of a static variable can be achieved in Python. The example was written as follows:

```
class MemberCounter:
    members = 0
    def init(self):
        MemberCounter.members += 1


m1 = MemberCounter()
m1.init()
m2 = MemberCounter()
m2.init()
```

after setting up the class and creating the objects, I printed the values of the 'members' attribute. These were the results:

MemberCounter.members = 2

m1.members = 2

m2.members = 2

And that's when I got confused. While I was expecting for 'MemberCounter.members = 2' the two other results made no sense to me - why would both of 'm1' and 'm2' objects' 'members' value be equal to 2? I thought that both of the values should have been 0 - if the only attribute that was chaged is the 'members' attribute which was attached to the MemberCounter class why would it cause any change to the own unique 'members' value of each of the class' objects. It looks like the fact that the 'members' attribute is addresed like 'MemberCounter.members += 1' in the init() function of each object, completely overrides the unique values which **m1.members** and **m2.members** refer to and redirects their pointers to the **MemberCounter.members** value making all the three pointers point at the same value

==> **m1.members = m2.members = MemberCounter.members.**

Moreover, I have tried defining the class in an opossite way (Increasing **self.members** instead of **MemberCounter.members**):

```
class MemberCounter:
    members = 0
    def init(self):
        self.members += 1


m1 = MemberCounter()
m1.init()
m2 = MemberCounter()
m2.init()
```

This definition yielded logical results (which got me curious about the above mentioned strange behaviour even more):

MemberCounter.members = 0

m1.members = 1

m2.members = 1

In short, I was curious about why the first class definition behaves in such a strange way? Why the mere '**MemberCounter**.members += 1' statement completely erased '**m1.members**' and '**m2.members**' own unique value and made it equal to the **MemberCounter.members** value.

I hope I was able to clearly present my problem and I will be extremly happy to get an insight about this strange behaviour :)

Comment: In the first of example your are changing the class variable whereas when you use `self` you are changing the instance's / generated object's variable. Does that make sense to you now?

Comment: But why does (in the first example) m1.members and m2.members have the same value as MemberCounter.members, if the only thing I was increasing is MemberCounter.members should'nt m1's and m2's own members value remain 0?

Comment: No, because you are increasing the class `MemerCounter`'s attribute `member` in the first example. One could say the objects do not have an individual attribute `member` in that example, rather `m1.members` and `m2.members` refer both to the class attribute `members`

Comment: Yep I think I got it now, thank you very much! Just to be sure - only by writing 'self.members' I am creating these unique members values for each of the object thus creating a distinction between the m1.members/m2.members and the MemberCounter.members values?

Comment: I think that's correct, yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you can *read* a static attribute with `instance.attribute` notation as alternative to the more natural `class.attribute` notation, is an intended feature in Python.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-static-class-data-and-static-class-methods):

> Both static data and static methods (in the sense of C++ or Java) are supported in Python.
>
> For static data, simply define a class attribute. To assign a new
> value to the attribute, you have to explicitly use the class name in
> the assignment:
>
> ```
> class C:
>     count = 0   # number of times C.__init__ called
>
>     def __init__(self):
>         C.count = C.count + 1
>
>     def getcount(self):
>         return C.count  # or return self.count
> ```
>
> `c.count` also refers to `C.count` for any `c` such that
> `isinstance(c, C)` holds, unless overridden by `c` itself or by some
> class on the base-class search path from `c.__class__` back to `C`.
>
> Caution: within a method of `C`, an assignment like `self.count = 42`
> creates a new and unrelated instance named “count” in `self`’s own dict.
> Rebinding of a class-static data name must always specify the class
> whether inside a method or not:
>
> `C.count = 314`

The paragraph just below the first code block explains your doubts. The "Caution" paragraph explains what you found logical.

Comment: I see, so basically as long as there is no explicit definition such as self.value = something, the values which I write in the class definition are basically passed down to the class' objects thus m1.members/m2.members were identical to MemberCounter.members all along (There was no unique 'members' value for m1/m2). Only in my second definition, by writing self.members I have created these unique 'members' values along the MemberCounter.members value thus behaving as I assumed. Did I get it right? Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, although I would phrase it differently: when you reference `self.value` and your instance does not have this attribute, the resolution mechanism will check the class' (static) attribute with that name, and if that fails, it will look in the superclass (if any), ...etc.