# Rebinding class attributes outside of methods

Tags: python

Something in the answer to this recent question about [manipulation of class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330002/python-3-does-the-direct-manipulation-of-a-class-attribute-override-the-same) jumped out at me and doesn't seem right.

The answer quotes a particular section from the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-static-class-data-and-static-class-methods) (I've emphasized the phrasing that's key to my question):

> Rebinding of a class-static data name must always specify the class ***whether inside a method or not***

That would seem to suggest that this trivial example based on the code in the FAQ should not work:

```
>>> class C:
...     count = 0
...     # optionally define methods that have nothing to do with count
...     count = count + 1
...
>>> C.count
1
```

`count` is a class attribute (what the FAQ section also calls a class-static data name, to use terminology analogous to languages with static types), there's a rebinding to a new value without specifying the class (e.g. `C.count`), and the rebinding is outside any method.

In fact, you **can't** do this by specifying the class, because the name `C` doesn't exist while the class is being defined:

```
>>> class C:
...    count = 0
...    C.count = C.count + 1
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in C
NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

If I understand things correctly, statements within a `class` block are executed as the class definition is created, and the resulting variables and other named objects (e.g. `def` statements) become class attributes and methods. Until that point, however, `count` is merely a local variable.

It would seem then that the FAQ language is misleading, that there's technically *no such thing* as a class (static) attribute in a class definition but outside a method, because the code in the class definition executes before class attributes exist.

Do I have that right?

**Update:** I probably should have posted the entire part of the FAQ because there's some confusion about the context:

> Caution: within a method of C, an assignment like self.count = 42 creates a new and unrelated instance named “count” in self’s own dict. Rebinding of a class-static data name must always specify the class whether inside a method or not

If the second sentence is talking about modifying the class attribute from outside the class, then it's VERY poorly written to specify "within a method of C" when it refers to rebinding.

Comment: Yes, you have it correct.

Comment: *"there's technically no such thing as a class (static) attribute outside a method"* - this part is not correct, you can access the attribute like `C.count` anywhere `C` is in scope, not necessarily just in a method.

Comment: When the FAQ says "whether inside a method or not", the "or not" is referring to rebindings outside the class body entirely.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: That's pretty misleading language then, whether you're inside or outside a method is irrelevant if you're outside the class body. It should just say "outside the class".

Comment: It's distinguishing between class attributes and instance attributes. There's an asymmetry involved: if you are *accessing* a class attribute, `self.count` can do so as long as there is no instance attribute `count` that shadows it. But `self.count = ...` *always* creates an instance attribute if it does not already exist, so you can never assign to a *class* attribute via an instance of the class: you must always use the class itself.

Comment: The "within a method" is not meant to be exhaustive. It's a FAQ, not a formal description of Python's semantics, so it's focusing on the common case of a programmer trying to update a class attribute by way of the current instance inside an instance method.

Comment: @kaya3: I meant within the class but outside a method. ```C``` is not in scope until the class is created. I revised the question to be more clear.

Comment: @sj95126 OK, but the part of the Python docs which you quoted, which says "whether inside a method or not", means it in the sense I described. I believe it's meant to draw a contrast with static methods in e.g. Java, where outside the class of course you have to qualify the method call as `C.count`, but inside the class `C` you wouldn't have to. So the Python docs are saying, unlike Java, in Python you do have to write `C.count` instead of `count` even inside a method of that class.

Comment: @kaya3: see my revision to the question. That bit follows "within a method of C" - if it means outside the class anywhere ```C``` is in scope then it's written rather ambiguously.

Comment: @sj95126 Looks like it's also written to clarify that in Python, unlike in Java, `self.count = ...` doesn't reassign the static attribute named `count`. In both Python and Java, `self.count` would give the value of the static attribute when no instance attribute of that name exists, but in Java, you can write `this.count = ...` to reassign a static field.

Comment: I feel like I'm not making my point clear. The FAQ is talking about "within a method of C" and then "whether inside a method or not". You can't have a class attribute inside a class but outside a method, because at the time the class block is executed, there is no class and there are no class attributes. The first sentence is about "within the class" so if the second sentence is about "outside the class" [at a time the class is in scope] it should say so clearly. There's no point in specifying "outside a method" if you're outside the class. Am I wrong to think the FAQ language is confusing?

Comment: @sj95126 I think you're right that the language is confusing, but you clearly understand the datamodel so not sure how you want this question answered. It would perhaps be better to propose a PR on the CPython docs explaining the issue and suggesting a clearer wording.

Comment: @chepner "But `self.count = ...` always creates an instance attribute" sorry to be the "well, actually" guy again  :)  `self.count = ...` can invoke a descriptor, which _might_ create an instance attribute.

Comment: @wim There are no descriptors in the example; let's not complicate matters :)

Comment: @wim: you answered it :-) I just wanted to make sure is that I **did** understand and that the confusing language didn't mean there's some edge case that means I misunderstand the model.

Answer (score 2):

At the point you are incrementing `count`, it is *not* yet a class attribute. It is just a name in the namespace being constructed to pass to the metaclass in order to define the new class.

The following are roughly equivalent:

```
class C:
    count = 0
    # optionally define methods that have nothing to do with count
    count = count + 1
```

and

```
import types


def make_class_namespace(d):
    count = 0
    count = count + 1
    d.update(count=count)
C = types.new_class('C', (), exec_body=make_class_namespace)
del make_class_namespace
```

There is no class attribute (or even class) until after `new_class` returns.

Comment: Invoking `types.new_class` using the `exec_body` keyword is perhaps more accurate. No difference in this simple case, but in the general case it is possible for the assignment statements in the class block to actually do something differently (by using a custom class namespace).

Comment: Good point. In the absence of any other keyword arguments to the class, though,  I think `new_class('C', (), metaclass=type, exec_body={'count': count})` and `type('C', (), {'count': count})` are equivalent.

Comment: Sure, makes sense, it's basically what I concluded at the end of my question. I just don't get why the FAQ is written the way it is. I updated my question with more detail.

Comment: @chepner  Not quite how it works- the third argument should be a mapping, and the exec_body is a callable, which allows using something other than a plain dict for the class namespace (can be useful for metaclass magic!).

Comment: The current code causes `TypeError`, because it's trying to do the equivalent of `class C(count=1):`.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now.